# Proving that $\sum_{v\in M_K, \,\,v\text{ archim.}} n_v=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, ramification

Let $L/K$ be an extension of number fields, $M_K, M_L$ complete sets of representatives of places at $K$ and $L$, respectively. I'm familiar with the formula:

$$\sum_{w\in M_L, \,\,w|v} n_w=[L:K]n_v\,\,\,\,\text{ for every }v\in M_K$$

However, I've read in a textbook that the result below could be deduced from the formula:

$$\sum_{v\in M_K, \,\,v\text{ archim.}} n_v=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$$

I can't see why this is so.

Comment: $n_v$ is the number of $\sigma \in Aut(K)$ leaving $|.|_v$ fixed ? Then  $n_v = 1$ for real places and $n_v = 2$ for complex places and it reduces to $[K:\mathbb{Q}]= \#\{$ embeddings $K \to \mathbb{C}\}$.

Comment: @reuns, $n_v:=[K_v:\mathbb{Q}_v]$ is the local degree. Is this related to what you said?

Comment: Leaving $|.|_v$ fixed is the same as $|.|_v$ continuous, by definition of $K_v$.